# Invalid Blocktype in Mage.php

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, exception

Hi i have this error in Log File

The Extension Free Besteller is deleted

Can anybody help me please

```
2016-09-19T20:22:26+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ungültiger Blocktyp: Mage_Freebestsellerssidebar_Block_Widget' in /home/blueb/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ung\xC3\xBCltiger Blo...')
#1 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('freebestsellers...', Array)
#2 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('freebestsellers...', '5fea1f5d240b1ce...')
#3 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('freebestsellers...', '5fea1f5d240b1ce...')
#4 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/blueb/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/blueb/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Comment: have your compile is enable ? if yes then do compilation again

Answer (score 1):

Go to CMS->Pages, edit the homepage and remove from the content section anything that resembles:

```
{{block type="freebestsellers/...." ....}}
```

Comment: there is nothing like bestseller in content of the home page

Comment: maybe the layout update section?

Comment: no there is nothing